# Parity signer fails to sign transaction with polkadot.js

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension

I have an account created with ParitySigner.
I am trying to add an account with a QR code to Polkadot.js and transfer money from that account with ParitySigner.

However, when I read the QR code in ParitySigner for signing, I get the following error: `Bad input data.

```
Bad input data. input generated within unknown network and could not be processed
add network with genesis hash xxxx and encryption sr25519`.
```

What do I need to do to transfer money with Polkadot.js?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, you need to add a network to Parity Signer. Please follow this tutorial:

https://paritytech.github.io/parity-signer/tutorials/Add-New-Network.html